# Detect nearby beacons with Bluez

Tags: ibeacon, bluez, ibeacon-android

I installed Bluez and I am trying to scan and get UUID Major, Minor and if possible mac address for nearby ibeacon. I found similar questions and they refer to a script which I found [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/ibeacon/idk/ibeacon_scan) . When I launch the script I get this error

> Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error

Did someone know how to solve the problem or has another solution ?
If I start transmitting with the beacon and then I start the scan I get no result at all and I have to interrupt the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test that the BlueZ installation is working properly on your Linux machine.  Try using the `hcitool dev` command to see if it lists attached devices properly.

You may want to refer to a BlueZ installation guide like [this one for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) to verify that you have your dongle set up properly.